# Angular UI multiple ui-select not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Multiple select in Angular UI-Select not working. This is my example:

```
 <ui-select multiple ng-model="params.filter()['manager']" class="form-control" reset-search-input="false">
                                <ui-select-match class="ui-select-match" allow-clear="true" placeholder="Manager">{{$select.selected.name }}</ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices class="ui-select-choices" repeat="item.id as item in selectArray.managerArray  | filter: $select.search "
                                                   refresh="refreshItem($select.search, 'UserGetSearch', 'managerArray')"
                                                   refresh-delay="0">
                                    <div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div> 
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  and why are you trying to bind `ng-model` to a function? I don't really think that will work.

Comment: it works with single selection (without multiple parameter)